# What is the proper way to claim something as your and someone elses?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

(For example, This is mine and John’s house, this is John’s and my house, this is my and John’s house..) without simply saying “our house”

Comment: In a similar vein, the title would be properly written as "yours and someone else's".

Answer (score 0):

This is my and John's house **or** this is John's and my house. The reason for this is because you should use a possessive determiner and not a possessive pronoun, as the pronoun is used in place of the noun, and the determiner is used before a noun. 
**My** is a *determiner* while **mine** is a *pronoun*.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide an explanation based on the rules of grammar, and also why you think the first is "better". For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)